# Bootstrap v4.0.3 Alpha Carousel Shadow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Aloha,

I'm working (still) on the bootstrap website and want to apply a (inset!) shadow to the carousel.
HTML looks like this:

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Tried to apply via

```
.carousel-item {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20rem rgba(0,0,0,1);

}
.carousel-item img {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

(and a few others which did not work).

Anybody got an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is hiding the shadow. Use a pseudo element with the box-shadow instead..

```
.carousel-item:before {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
}
```

<kbd>[Codeply Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/HTKVcweqHB)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I think the inset shadow is here, but no visible,  then the picture fill the container.

try this:

```
.carousel-item{
    padding: 20rem
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 20rem rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

or read this: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h